# Get only read data with SNMPv3

Tags: snmp

I have a question about SNMPv3. I'm doing my internship and they wanted me to get read only data and I cant figure out how to do it. I hope you guys can help me

Comment: Time to find a good book, not to post such broad questions on SO.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 commands in SNMP that allow you to read data from device:

- GET
- GET-NEXT
- GET-BULK

The Get-Bulk is supported starting from SNMPv2C.

The main difference between SNMPv3 and earlier versions of the protocol is security model. There is so called **User-based Security Model (USM).** So first of all you'll need to configure security principals (users) on SNMP agent/device side.

After that you'll need to download SNMP tool(s) to send your SNMP requests/commands. For example if you use **NET-SNMP** package you can do the following:

```
snmpgetnext -v 3 -n "" -u MD5User -a MD5 -A "The Net-SNMP Demo Password" -l authNoPriv test.net-snmp.org sysUpTime
```

You can also use graphical tools like **NetDecision MIB Browser** (http://netmechanica.com/products/?prod_id=1009) to query the devices via SNMPv3.

[image: MIB Browser main window]
You'll have to configure SNMP User Profiles in SNMP User Manager tool just like this:
[image: SNMP User Manager main window]

Comment: Thank you so much Andrew